# Using custom pipe in angular 6 for sorting

Tags: typescript, sorting, angular6

> i want to sort columns on on my angular table and want to use a pipe kind of thing
>
> but not able to do so Can someone please guide me to the correct material or 
>    preference and i want to create a custom sorting
>
> i want to know how to call this from my html table headers

my filter goes like this

```
export class SortGridPipe implements PipeTransform {
transform(records: Array<any>, args?: any): any {
    return records.sort(function (a, b) {
        if (a[args.property] < b[args.property]) {
            return -1 * args.order;
        }
        else if (a[args.property] > b[args.property]) {
            return 1 * args.order;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: How do you call this pipe in a template? What are you passing as args?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to let the pipe take parameters when certain event happen and expect the records to sort on that, I believe that is not possible. The data transform only happens when you data changes. In this case you might be better off by using a function instead of a pipe.

Or If you you are passing a pipe like:

```
     <tr  *ngFor='let row of (data | yourpipe  ) ' >
        <td> {{your td data}} </td>
    </tr>
```

and you are modifying data by pushing or slicing, and you are not seeing the sorting properly take place, in this case you need to make you pipe an impure one. like:

```
   @Pipe({
       name: 'yourpipe',
       pure: false
        })
```

This is related to Angular's change detection mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for the help already made changes and it's working Thanks for putting so much effort